# opencv feature detector crash with unhandled exception error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, feature-detection

feature detector fails when used in simple program in visual studio 2010. I am using opencv 2.4.2 and also checked on 2.4.1. Only thing that is being done is to create a feature detector and use that to detect keypoints in an image. I get unhandled exception crash pointing to a function named "detecImpl()" inside detectors.cpp (i.e. features2d\detectors.cpp line:65). This error is really stuck and has taken enormous amount of time so any help is really appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp" 
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

using namespace std; 
using namespace cv; 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{ 
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> featureDetector; 
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> descriptorExtractor; 
featureDetector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SURF"); 
descriptorExtractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("SURF"); 
cv::Mat imageColor; 
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("car1.jpg", 0); 
    cv::cvtColor(image, imageColor, CV_GRAY2BGR); 
try{ 
imshow("Test Image",imageColor); 
cv::waitKey(3000); 
} 
catch(cv::Exception exc) 
{ 
cout << "CV error occured : " + exc.msg; 
} 
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> currentKeypoints; 

try{ 
    featureDetector->detect(image,currentKeypoints);   //This line generates the error but no exception is caught .... 
    } 
catch(cv::Exception exc) 
{ 
cout << "CV error occured : " + exc.msg; 
return -1; 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out. In new versions of opencv the SURF/SIFT are distributed in a separate library which needs to be initialized before creation of feature detector.

Comment: For those wondering, the initialization is: `cv::initModule_nonfree()`

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me using OpenCV 2.4.2 on VS2010.

I found the following to work:
FAST, STAR, ORB, BRISK, GFFT, and Harris.

SIFT, SURF will work after including the non-free features and initiating them.

While Dense & SimpleBob crashed.

The one that gave the best results relative to the rest was FAST (in performance + accuracy)